# Can I make a closed-source implementation from scratch of a GPL-licensed library?

Tags: gpl

I've found a paper describing a particular algorithm I'd like to use, and published with the paper is a GPL licensed source code for the algorithm. I am wondering if I can re-implement the algorithm from the paper (obviously without using any of the original code), distribute it closed source, and not be in violation of the original GPL license agreement.

As a corollary, what if I make some (minor) modifications to the algorithm along the way?

Comment: Regardless of whether this is legally feasible, *why* would you want to do this???

Comment: Um, isn't that pretty obvious? I like the ideas of the paper, would like to implement some/all of them, and don't want to be constrained by the GPL license if possible. I want to know to what extent someone else's GPL implementation restricts my own

Comment: It's sort of a separate question, but I'm also interested in the moral aspect too: regardless of the legality, I'm guessing what I propose would be frowned upon by the GPL community...

Comment: And the spreading of "GPL virus" by the GPL community is in turn frowned on by many others. The GPL is a highly divisive licence and it is as valid to take the moral high-ground against it as it is for it.

Comment: @DavidArno ha maybe I should have said "political aspect"? I'd like to respect the author's intent, so will try to stick to the spirit of GPL

Comment: @DavidArno I disagree the GPL itself is the issue (that'd be the legal aspect, which I'm uninterested in). Look at the wording of the question: "make it closed-source". This is unethical. Why would I help a freeloader with advice on how to bypass the ethical implications of taking something open and trying to make it closed?

Comment: @dmagree That's better :) Trying to stick to the spirit of sharing Free software is way better than attempting to find loopholes of dubious moral integrity.

Comment: @AndresF. but really what is GPL protecting? The ideas of the paper or the hours that he spent coding it up? I am not convinced that all software should be free, and so I am trying to give the author what is his due while at the same time using publically available information to work on a project that might end up closed source. I think there is a middle ground (especially if I change and improve on the original ideas).

Comment: @AndresF. I think I agree that a strict reimplementation might be legally ok but against the spirit of GPL. I also think that it would be very difficult to end up with a strict reimplementation if you weren't looking at the source code and legally in violation of GPL.

Comment: "Why would I help a freeloader with advice on how to bypass the ethical implications of taking something open and trying to make it closed?" This is comical. Usually people who care about ethics, want to take opportunities to tell others about ethics, so that they will also, you know, care about ethics. Also the wording seems to imply that, not only do you want free-software, but you also want freeloaders to feel bad, in particular. :) Maybe you meant "legal implications" rather than "ethical"?

Comment: @AndresF. Of course the GPL is the issue. It is preventing the OP and others using this piece of code in commercial applications. It is the reason the OP is looking to rewrite the code. If the paper's author had used any other open source licence, this question wouldn't have even needed asking.

Comment: @ChrisBeck No, I meant *ethical*. It's entirely possible there are legal ways, but what I meant to say is that there aren't *ethical* ways of bypassing the GPL. It's about the *spirit* of Free software, not about the *legality*.

Comment: @DavidArno No, the issue is trying to take something open and make it closed. Look at the wording. It's not "I have this which is GPL and it may be incompatible with this other license, how can I make this work?", it's "how can I make it **closed**"?

Comment: @dmagree The GPL protects a piece of software, not the paper and not ideas. The paper is a different issue. What I find telling is that you want to take something openly given to you, in the spirit of sharing, and make it *closed*, i.e. find ways to prevent other people of freely sharing it. I find this the wrong attitude.

Comment: @AndresF., at this point, I'd hand over to the OP to explain, if he cares to, the reasons behind wanting to created a closed source version of the algorithm. As you rudely referred to him as a freeloader, I wouldn't bother to respond if I were the OP. I'd simply report you and then ignore you henceforth.

Comment: @AndresF., not everyone who uses the GPL understands it in the same way. For instance, the FSF decided that "tivoization" is an unfair use of free software and lobbied for terms against it in the GPL v3. And the linux kernel developers don't agree, and continue to distribute under the GPL v2 instead. If someone wants to take GPL v2 code and put it on a tivo is that ethical? I don't think you can say without more information. The point of laws and licenses is to help people figure out what they *can* do -- in a broad licensing question like this raising ethical concerns isn't appropriate IMO.

Comment: @DavidArno Taking the effort of others and trying to close it to other people is almost the definition of freeloading. This is what the Free Software community fights against. If the shoe fits...

Comment: @ChrisBeck Yes, not everyone understands the GPL the same way, and yes, I indeed want freeloaders to feel bad. The evidence that this isn't truly about the GPL but about *ethics* is pretty clear to me: after all, if someone cared about the *spirit* of the law, why would they ask about this instead of emailing the paper's authors? ("Hey, I read your paper. Would it be ok if I reimplemented your algorithm in my closed-source program?"). The only reason to ask this question here instead is if you're dimly aware the authors might not be ok with this, but people might help you find a loophole.

Comment: @ChrisBeck It's the same regarding "tivoization", by the way. Whenever there is a doubt about how you can use a piece of Free software -- something that's not spelled out in the GPL but you suspect might be against its spirit -- you should ask the author(s) first instead of trying to find a loophole. It's the Right Thing To Do (tm).

Comment: @AndersF.: The way I see it there are two parties, the licensor, and the licensees. The GPL sets up a clearly written regime of rights. The licensees need to be able to know their rights -- the right answer cannot be "anyone who wants to know what their exact rights are is clearly a freeloader and should be shunned". And the right answer cannot be "you should not do anything without the upstream dev's permission", that is not practical, or legally speaking, how it works. The terms are put in writing, that's the license.

Comment: People need to feel free to ask questions about the GPL or it cannot serve its purpose. People need to be comfortable with it, feel like they know what it means, what it obligates them to do, and so forth, or they simply won't use it. OP appears to be trying to figure out how to *respect* the GPL and we should help him/her, and anyone else who might find this question later.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Asking questions about the GPL is fine. But look at the OP's second comment: *"I'm guessing what I propose would be frowned upon by the GPL community"*. They *know* what they are asking is morally dubious. This is an *ethical* question disguised as a technical/legal question about the GPL. Asking how you can take something free and make it nonfree (or "closed") should be frowned upon. It seems to me this is a question asked in semi-bad faith. When in doubt about a specific paper, *ask the authors*. This IS the default good-faith course of action. It's not too much to ask this.

Comment: @AndresF. No, I totally disagree. This really has very little to do with the GPL, the OP is asking if he can use ideas from a paper, and unless they are patented, he can. The FSF and in particular RMS are vehemently opposed to software patents -- no one should be able to own what are essentially mathematical and algorithmic ideas, that is our inheritance as thinking human beings. It doesn't matter what the "reference implementation" is licensed as -- I don't think there is a cogent argument to be made that what OP asks is unethical.

Comment: @ChrisBeck I don't disagree with what you've said except the last part. The OP him/herself suspects this, as evidenced in their second comment (the "frowned upon" comment). No idea why you've brought RMS into this, because *he* definitely thinks closed-source software is unethical by definition. But that's neither here nor there. Bottom line: ask the paper's authors; don't ask here. *Especially* if -- as I've been saying -- this isn't really a question about the GPL. Not sure what you're disagreeing with here...

Comment: @AndresF. Thanks for the comments. While I think you are claiming to understand my motives better that I do ;) I think you make some fair points. My main purpose for asking here is to better understand my rights and better understand how GPL is understood in the community. If all anyone had to do was ask the author, then what is the point of a legal license at all? The author could have an off-the-wall interpretation that I would have taken as gospel had I not asked around. In any case this has been a very interesting discussion which seems justification enough for the post.

Comment: @AndresF. And with regards to my "frowned upon" the FSF community would frown upon ANY closed source software, so I'm not sure why that should necessarily make what I propose unethical. Unless you think all closed source software is unethical.

Comment: @dmagree Well, the FSF considers proprietary software unethical; or at least, RMS does. But I agree with you that's not the issue here. What is the issue, in my opinion, is that in this case the ethical thing to do is to contact the authors of the paper. That is, if you care about doing what's right. The GPL itself is a red herring; it's an artifact of copyright law. If there were no copyright, the GPL would be unnecessary, as admitted by its proponents.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question of what constitutes a derivative work and can only be properly answered by a lawyer.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice:

In the US as regards to software there are generally two kinds of IP you need to worry about: Patents and Copyrights.

If an algorithm published in an academic paper is *patented* then you cannot use it -- the ideas and methods themselves are protected intellectual property. You would need to license it from the patent holder.

If it is only that the reference implementation is *copyrighted*, then if you reimplement the algorithm from scratch without using the original source code, it is then not a derivative work of the copyrighted material.

As I understand, a very safe way to do it is if you give the part of the paper describing the algorithm to your coworker, and she implements it, having never seen the reference implementation. But again, I am not a lawyer.

Comment: Also, I understand this sort of thing varies greatly from one jurisdiction to another. eg, in the US you're far more likely to run afoul of someone than overseas. Personally, I would contact the author of the paper first …

Comment: How can the OP reimplement the algorithm without looking at the original? They've already looked. You can't unring that bell.

Comment: @ScantRoger, that isn't what I said.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you find it necessary to start an answer with "I am not a lawyer" then you're safe in assuming that the question is off-topic for the site.

Comment: It probably isn't necessary to start the answer like that -- I don't think very many people would confuse what I wrote for real legal advice. However it's always safer for me to write that whenever I write about "the law" in an online context like this. Is there any harm in it? Also if the question is off-topic shouldn't you argue that from the question rather than from one of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the code is GPL licensed affects what you are allowed to do with that code. It does not affect what you are allowed to do with the paper, or what code you are allowed to write yourself.

Unless the paper itself came with some kind of license stating "you may not create closed-source implementations of this algorithm or modified versions thereof", you should be fine.

Of course, if by "reimplementing" you really meant "transcribing the GPL-licensed code token by token", then you'd be creating a derivative work and the GPL restrictions would be in full force. But I assume that's not what you meant.

And this does not exclude the possibility that the algorithm in the paper is patented or copyrighted. You'd definitely need to talk to a lawyer if that happens to be the case.

Comment: Since you mentioned the "moral aspect", the short version is that the philosophy espoused by the FSF (the creators of the GPL) is simply that [all software should be "free"](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html). But ensuring that software remains free forever [requires a "copyleft" license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/copyleft.en.html) such as the GPL, or else someone can retroactively make it non-free by doing the sort of thing you intend to do. You evil, evil man. But in all seriousness, I suspect most programmers wouldn't mind at all.

Comment: I do mind. Taking something open and trying to find a loophole to make it closed... I definitely frown upon *that* :/ Whether it's the GPL or other Free Software license doesn't matter to me. The *intent* matters, and the intent in this case is wrong.